# Image Preview not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, safari, cross-browser

I'm using the following code to preview image on the client before uploading it to server, works in Chrome but not in Safari. Why?

JavaScript.

```
$('#imageUpload').change(function(){        
            readImgUrlAndPreview(this);
            function readImgUrlAndPreview(input){
                 if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                        var reader = new FileReader();
                        reader.onload = function (e) {                          
                            $('#imagePreview').attr('src', e.target.result);
                            }
                      };
                      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
                }   
});
```

HTML.

```
<img src="" id="imagePreview" alt="Preview Image" width="40px" height="40" style="border:none !important; border-width:0px !important;"/> 
  <input type="file" name="imageUpload" id="imageUpload"/> 
<label for="imageUpload" id="UploadImage1Label" >Upload image</label>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your browser not supported FileReader API. You should check the safari version. Here is the link, you can reference it: http://caniuse.com/filereader.
It's supported from version 6.0.